# Advantage Table File in use error. How can I resolve?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, advantage-database-server

I'm having trouble getting a certain table to open up in more then one instance of my program.
Whats happening is I'm trying to allow users to open up and replace a current table(part of a data dictionary - FileForm.ImagesTable) with an older table (not included in the data dictionary).  It works great for one instance of the program but when we try to open up that same file simultaneously on another instance.  I get the following error.

**FileName.ADT This file is in use.  Enter a new name or close the file that's open in another program.**

Below is the code I have reassigning the table name and datapath to the selected table.

```
OpenDialog1.FileName := '*.adt';
OpenDialog1.Filter := 'Software 6.0 Files (*.adt)|*.adt|Software 5.x Files (*.dbf)|*.dbf';
OpenDialog1.InitialDir := DataPath;
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
    Str1 := Trim(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    if Length(Str1) = 0 then
        Exit;
    DSImage.Enabled := False;

    with FileForm.ImagesTable do
    begin
        Active := False;
        AfterOpen := FileForm.TableOther.AfterOpen;
        DataBaseName := ExtractFilePath(Str1);   
        TableName :=  ExtractFileName(Str1);
        Active := True;
    end;
 end;
```

---

**Edit** * Using Advtantage 8.1, Seems to be a windows error because the error happens in the dialogue window.  And yes Exclusive is set to false.

[image: error]

---

Any thougths on why this is happening and how this could be resolved are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Trevor: if you're trying to make structural changes to the table, you probably need exclusive (locked) access.  Try opening the table exclusively to perform the restructuring.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error? Is it an Advantage error, or a Windows error? (I see it's not a restructuring issue, but @Robert's comment may still apply: Have you checked the `ImagesTable.Exclusive` property? If you're opening it with `Exclusive = True` in the first instance of your app, the second would get an error about trying to open it.)

Comment: Hey Robert, the table i'm trying to replace has the same structure as the existing table.

Comment: Please clarify the specific error type (Windows or ADS). If you're not sure, do a screen capture of the error dialog and add it to your answer.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's a Windows error. I can't replicate the problem, though. Is there a reason you don't just make the `ImagesTable` a free table instead of part of the data dictionary (since you're basically allowing users to remove/replace it at will)?

Comment: Okay thanks, I am just curious did you try to replicate the problem on windows 7?  I have reason to believe it may only happen on windows 7.  I was going to work on your suggestion, but I thought I would try to do what the other poster said first and it worked!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are only using the Open Dialog to get the name of the table.
On the Open dialog try setting the option [ofShareAware](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Dialogs_TOpenOption.html)

> OpenDialog1.Options := OpenDialog1.Options + [ ofShareAware ];

Once the table is open with Advantage the mode is both deny write, deny read and as a result will return a sharing error if anything non-advantage tries to open the table.

Answer (score 4):

You're not clear on the specific error - is it a Windows error or an Advantage error?

If it's a Windows error, it may be because you've specified exclusive access to the table (`ImageTable.Exclusive = True`). This would mean that the first instance of the app could open it, but subsequent tries would fail with a `File is in use` error.

If it's an Advantage error, the Advantage help file (here in [v11's documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/devguide_understanding_and_using_data_dictionaries.htm), since you didn't specify a version of ADS - note it's in a frame, so you may need to use [this link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html), navigate to `Advantage Developers Guide`, expand the `Part 1->Chapter 4 - Dictionaries->Understanding Dictionaries` topic) says:

> A data dictionary is a special file that serves as the sole access point for database tables

Note the **sole access point**. Once a table is in the data dictionary, it belongs to the data dictionary. You're trying to replace that reference with something outside the scope of the dictionary, and that isn't allowed. I'm pretty sure that the problem is related to that - ADS puts a proprietary lock on tables that are included in the dictionary, and controls access to those files through the server by way of the dictionary.

You'll need to either remove the table from the dictionary and use it as a free table, or come up with a different strategy for removing the current data and replacing it with other data to preserve the integrity of the dictionary.

Comment: I see your point with the data dictionary server as a sole access point.  But I do believe the error is a windows error.  And Exclusive is set to false.